# 3 форма нормализации БД MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Необходимо сделать таблицу с делами/задачами в БД для CRM-системы. Задача может быть привязана как к сделке, так и к клиенту, и к заявке, поставке и др.

Вопросы:

1. Как правильно организовать структуру этой таблицы?
2. Помимо столбцов для самой задачи (комментарий, срок и т.д.), добавить столбцы с client_id, lead_id, sale_id?
3. Правильно ли будет, если, к примеру, задача привязана именно к клиенту, поля lead_id и sale_id сделать NULL?
4. Или же лучше вынести в отдельную таблицу связи задачи с другими сущностями?

Comment: Надо начинать с определения со сколькими сущностям одновременно может быть связана задача. Если она связана скажем с клиентом, то она всегда связана _только с одним клиентом_ или может быть с несколькими. Если задача связана с клиентом, может ли она одновременно быть связана скажем с сделкой

Answer (score 0):

Сделайте отдельно таблицу с задачами и отдельно таблицу связей (с клиентами, сделками, заявками, поставками и т.д.). Для последней достаточно всего 3 колонки:

1. id задачи
2. тип, к какой сущности привязываем таблицу (к клиенту, сделке, заявке и т.д.)
3. id сущности (клиента, сделки и т.д.)

> Правильно ли будет, если, к примеру, задача привязана именно к
>   клиенту, поля lead_id и sale_id сделать NULL?

используйте вышеуказанный вариант, а поля client_id, lead_id и sale_id объединяйте в одно поле id сущности (саму сущность будем определять по полю тип, его можно сделать smallint или tinyint).

Comment: А как потом использовать такую таблицу в реальных запросах?

Comment: Присоединяюсь к вопросу выше. В запросе к БД к таблице с задачами, при JOIN'ах к таблице со связями, я буду получать лишь тип сущности. Каким образом мне сделать запросы к таблицам с сущностями?

Comment: здесь все просто. например, чтобы получить список задач, которые привязаны к клиенту делаем запрос в таблицу связей, где в условиях WHERE указываем client_id и тип (допустим мы условились, что клиенты у нас идут под типом 1). далее в самом простом варианте (без JOIN'ов и сопоставления данных) по каждой найденной строчке делаем 2 запроса в таблицы с клиентами и задачами, где получаем дополнительную информацию о них. но все же лучше использовать JOIN'ы или сопоставление (где потом делается всего 2 запроса: в таблицу с клиентами со списком client_id и в таблицу с задачами со списком task_id).